# error using express-jwt: jwt is not a function

Tags: node.js, passport.js, express-jwt

I'm using express-jwt in my project but I'm getting this error, I couldn't find the solution

```
 import jwt from "express-jwt";
    const getTokenFromHeaders = (req) => {
        const { headers: { authorization } } = req
    
        if (authorization && authorization.spilt(' ')[0] === 'Token') {
            return authorization.split(' ')[1]
        }
        return null
    }
    
    const auth = {
        required: jwt({
            secret: " /\-l/\Y",
            userProperty: 'payload',
            getToken: getTokenFromHeaders
        }),
        optional: jwt({
            secret: "/\-l/\Y",
            userProperty: 'payload',
            getToken: getTokenFromHeaders,
            credentialsRequired: false,
        })
    }
    
    export default auth
```

this use

```
router.post("/login", auth.optinal, (req, res, next) => {
      const { body: { user } } = req
    
      if (!user.email && !user.password) {
        return res.status(402).json({
          errors: "Eposta veya şifre yanlış ! ",
        });
    
        return passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, (err, passportUser, info) 
 => {
          if (err) {
            return next(err)
          }
          if (passportUser) {
            const user = passportUser
            user.token = passportUser.genareteJWT();
            return res.json({ user: user.toAuthJSON() })
          }
          return res.status(400).info;
    
        })(req, res, next)
      }
    })
```

and error message:

> required: jwt({
> ^
> TypeError: jwt is not a function
> at file:///C:/Users/atala/Desktop/atalayapp-main/backend/middleware/auth/auth.js:12:15
> at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)
> at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules
> /esm/loader:385:24)
> at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
> at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)

Comment: note in docs Migration from v6 - The middleware function is now available as a named import rather than a default one: `import { expressjwt: jwt } from 'express-jwt'`